# How should I pick which source specific multicast address to use?

Tags: udp, multicast, ipv4

["The 232.0.0.0/8 (IPv4) and FF3x::/32 (IPv6) block is reserved for use by source-specific multicast."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Source-specific_multicast)

So I assume this means I can use any address from 232.0.0.0 to 232.255.255.255 for source-specific multicasting.  What should I be considering when I choose which address to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose whatever you want. It only has to be unique per sending system. There is no algorithm for this. It's *source specific* after all ☺

Comment: ["The source discovery burden on the network can become significant when the number of sources is large."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-specific_multicast) -  This was one of my concerns - thought there might be a tool to check the activity on an ip.

Comment: The question is about group addresses, not sources. When a source is going to start a new multicast stream it doesn't matter which group address it chooses as long as it's unique to the source.

Comment: And you quote a line from the explanation of ASM that is there as contrast to show why SSM is better. The whole point if SSM is that source discovery isn't needed.